# Как игнорировать запросы клиента на сервер?

Tags: java, ajax, веб-программирование, java-ee, primefaces

При низкой скорости соединения, пользователь успевает сделать множество действий на клиенте, пока сервер обработает первое действие.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Можно ли как-то игнорировать запросы пока не выполнится самый первый? Сформировать очередь, может, как подобные проблемы вообще решаются, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - это заставить пользователя подождать, пока сервер обработает его запрос, например, показав ему модальное окно "Подождите" с вращающимся колесом или progress bar.

Ставить запросы в очередь, очевидно, сложнее, и тут все зависит от конкретной прикладной задачи.

Очередь будет накапливать изменения до какого-то разумного размера.
А в случае переполнения должен быть показан все тот же модальный диалог "Подождите".

Очередь не сделает ваш сервер или соединение быстрее. Она позволяет сгладить задержки, накапливая изменения и передавая их в фоне, равномерно используя соединение и возможности сервера (а не пиками), позволяя пользователю тем временем продолжать работу.

Comment: Продолжительность отображения ни к чему конкретному не привязывается. Создается таймер в несколько секунд или десятков секунд. В нем вы делаете асинхронный фоновый запрос на сервер "Обработка выполнена?". Если да, то закрываете окно.

Comment: хмм.. Интересно. А у Вас нет примера под рукой?
А в какой момент открывается окно? Мы же не можем каждое событие ещё руками подвязывать на открытие окна?

Comment: @Saint Не могу знать, можете ли вы "руками его подвязывать", потому что не знаю какого рода события и детали задачи. Я обрисовал лишь общепринятую практику. Чтобы получить ответ, касающийся деталей реализации (какие флаги и т.п.), нужно более подробно поставить вопрос - с более подробным описанием вашей задачи и тем решением, которое у вас есть сейчас.